# Unable to access dockerized .net core 6 application using IP

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

I'm running the container using this command
`docker run -d --restart=always -p 0.0.0.0:5055:5000  testcommand`
I'm getting Connected to localhost. when run `telnet localhost 5055`
in server but from browser not getting any response.

Comment: Why are you trying to use telnet to connect to an aspnet service? If you `curl -v localhost:5055`  what do you get? Are there any logs shown in the aspnet application?

Comment: *   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149999 ms for 3 (transfer 0x5562e89bafb0)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5562e89bafb0)
* connect to ::1 port 5055 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149999 ms for 3 (transfer 0x5562e89bafb0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5055 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5055
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 17:00:25 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: Have you got an endpoint configured in your app? Try `curl -v localhost:5055/myEndpoint`

Comment: * connect to ::1 port 5055 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149999 ms for 3 (transfer 0x556662fa1fb0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5055 (#0)
> GET /Update HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5055
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 17:09:49 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: Any logs in Kestrel?

Comment: im not getting any response from browser my server port is open  0.0.0.0:5055->5000/tcp

Comment: Sure, but in the actual container, what output is kestrel giving you? 

Have you tested the application outside of docker?